# R {ggplot2} define the bars columns by color within applied facet_grid()?

Tags: r, plot

I have a basic plot of two variables on multiple levels, which I can display by facet_grid(). As a result, I have a set of barks of the same colors, arranged by levels of two variables.

However, what if I want to indicate, that my data are from different source?
i.e. from Friday to Sunday - from RED data, for Thursday from BLACK data.

Is there a way how can I indicate on my final plot by colors, that my data are from RED and BLACK datasets?

Something like:

(example taken from : http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Facets_(ggplot2)/)

[image]

Example code:

```
require(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

head(tips)

ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=2,colour="white")+ 
  facet_grid(sex ~ day)
```

**I know that I can change those colors eaily in Inkscape, by maybe there is a simple R based solution?**

---

*the data source (RED and BLACK) I will specify in Figure caption: no need to to specify that in the plot.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By assigning `day` to the `fill` aesthetic and manually defining the colour for the different values of `day` you can get the desired effect.

The following code:

```
ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, fill = day)) + geom_histogram(binwidth=2, colour = "white")+ 
  facet_grid(sex ~ day) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Fri" = "Red", "Sat" = "Red", "Sun" = "Red", "Thur" = "Black"))
```

gives the following plot:

[image]

The legend could be hidden by adding `+ guides(fill = "none")`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
ggplot(tips, aes(x=total_bill, fill=day=="Thur")) + geom_histogram(binwidth=2)+ 
  facet_grid(sex ~ day) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "black"))
```

Edit: added colors "black" and "red"